# Making a bezier curve sway/swing with anchor points at both ends

Tags: bezier-curves

Edit: I'm a beginner to Blender

I'm trying to make a bridge sway from side to side with both the ends of the bezier curve staying in place while the middle moves from side to side.

Currently, a single bezier curve is used to make the curved shape of the bridge.
I have tried:

- Using a second, horizontal bezier curve, although I could not get the ends to be pinned in place and the two curves didn't synergise well and produce warped results
- Using the 'Simple Deform' modifier and twisting, but, instead of the ends, the centre stayed static. Additionally, I had very little control over it.
- Changing handles so that there were single points instead, but this meant that when I tried to bend it, I had to manually make a curved line by moving vertices, which resulted in a curve that did not look good (and took a long time to edit).

[image: A simplistic bridge]

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could make an animation that looks like it's swaying from side-to-side?
I'm trying to make it swing from side-to-side so that the displacement is greatest in the middle and has zero at the ends.

**The eventual goal is to have it swing from side-to-side as if in strong winds and then split in the middle and fall down, hanging from each end.** (Although I'll cross that bridge when I come to it).

Comment: what about hooking the curve vertices to bones and move them?

Comment: I would actually do this with rigid bodies and forces :-P

Comment: so you could create an edge with several vertices that will be your cloth, parent empties to each of its vertices, then hook the curve vertices to these empties, there must be something like that